# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sin{\frac{1}{n}})(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}})(\cos n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$|(\sin{\frac{1}{n}})(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}})(\cos n)|\le|(\sin(\frac{1}{n}))(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}})|$

Since 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sinh(x)}{x}=1$

Thus $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{|\sin(\frac{1}{n})\sinh(\frac{1}{n})|}{1}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=1$$

We know that $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges so $|\sin(\frac{1}{n})\sinh(\frac{1}{n})|$ converges. Then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sin{\frac{1}{n}})(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}})(\cos n)$$ converges absolutely. So it converges.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct. Though, the bit "we know that $1/n^2$ converges so $|\sin(1/n) \sinh(1/n)|$ converges" is out of place. You need to say, instead, that $\sum 1/n^2$ is convergent gives $\sum |\sin(1/n) \sinh(1/n)|$ is convergent

Answer (score 0):

Note that the series should start from $n=1$, as $1/0$ is not defined.

For the sine, you have the inequality $$\tag{1}|\sin x|\leq x.$$ For the hyperbolic sine, you can use the mean value theorem to show that, if $x\in[0,1]$, 
$$\tag{2}
|\sinh x|=|\sinh x - \sinh0|=|x|\,|\cosh\xi|
$$
where $\xi\in[0,x]$. In particular $|\xi|\leq1$, so 
$$
|\cosh\xi|=\left|\frac{e^\xi+e^{-\xi}}2\right|\leq\frac {e^\xi+e^{-\xi}}2\leq\frac{e+1}2\leq2.$$ Going back to $(2)$, we obtain
$$\tag{3}
|\sinh x|\leq 2|x|
$$
if $x\in [0,1]$. Now, using $(1)$ and $(3)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\sin\frac1n\,\sinh\frac1n\,\cos n|
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\sin\frac1n|\,|\sinh\frac1n|\,|\cos n|\\ \ \\
&\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}3<\infty
\end{align}
so by comparison the series converges absolutely.